# Свой json response в Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

Пробую построить свое API на Laravel.

1. В Ларе используется response()->json($data), однако хотелось бы использовать свою логику в ответе. Есть способ?
2. Необходимо в ответе отдавать время, потраченное на выполнение запроса.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь **макросами**, определить которые можно в методе boot() сервис-провайдера AppServiceProvider.

Там же можно высчитать и скорость работы приложения, используя **константу LARAVEL_START**:

```
public function boot()
{
    Response::macro('Myjson', function ($data) {
        $speed = microtime(true) - LARAVEL_START;
        return Response::json([
            'path' => request()->path(), 
            'speed' => round($speed, 3),
            'data' => $data], $code);
    });
}
```

И вызывайте в своих контроллерах:

```
return response()->Myjson($data);
```